# Make a pushbutton invisible in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I was wondering if there was a way to make a pushbutton invisible while still being functional?

Comment: Does this work https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyqt5-hide-push-button-on-click/ ?

Comment: Sure, just set the background-color, border-color, and text color to transparent, and bobs your uncle.  You might need to do the same for each of the pseudo-states as well

Comment: @KyJames why do you want to make invisible an element that needs visual hints in order to be used? Are you trying to make something (like a label or image) "clickable" by putting an invisible button over it?

Comment: @Alexander Thank you! I made everything transparent and it's working the way I want it to :)

Comment: @KyJames  Your welcome.  Ill post it as an answer too

Answer (score 2):

Yes you definitely can using `QStyleSheets`.

```
QPushButton,
QPushButton:default,
QPushButton:hover,
QPushButton:selected,
QPushButton:disabled,
QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
```

Setting the border color, background color, and text color to transparent will make it invisible, but still functional.

Answer (score -1):

simply use self.pushButton.hide(). If you need to hide it. When needed you can show it again.

Comment: The OP clearly wrote "while still being functional", which isn't possible if the button is not visible.